# How to write a function that checks if a person has logged into a Discord server?

Tags: python, discord, client, bots

I am trying to build a discord bot with a few features. I have been following article about how to make it and I have stumbled upon an idea that I want the bot, when a certain person has logged into chat, to write a message to him. I have no idea how to write that, so if you could help me I would be eternally grateful. This is my code so far

```
# importuj discord.py i konektovan na discord API.
import DISCORD

# GETS THE CLIENT OBJECT FROM DISCORD.PY. CLIENT IS SYNONYMOUS WITH BOT.
bot = DISCORD.client()
# EVENT LISTENER FOR WHEN THE BOT HAS SWITCHED FROM OFFLINE TO ONLINE.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # brojac u koliko je servera bot trenutno
    guild_count = 0

    # provjerava sve servere gdje je
    for guild in bot.GUILDS:
        #izbaci ime servera
        print(f"- {guild.id} (name:{guild.name})")
        #poveca broj servera za 1

        guild_count = guild_count + 1

    #izbaci u koliko je sve servera
    print("Discord bot is in" + str(guild_count) + "guilds.")

 #EVENT LISTENER FOR WHEN A NEW MESSAGE IS SENT TO A CHANNEL.

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
     #provjeri sta je napisano na server
     if message.content == 'hello':
         # SENDS BACK A MESSAGE TO THE CHANNEL.
         await message.channel.send("Selam alejk")

# upali bota, ovo u zagradi je TOKEN od bota
bot.run("ODIyODM0NTQyNjY2MTg2Nzkz.YFYCYg.ZdGFpYWdnMPGiOrSB5HbGDTAZxo")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to do something when someone is typing in a chat?
If it is you can define a function discord.on_typing():

```
import discord

bot = discord.client()

@bot.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, datetime):
    # something to do
```

You can look at the python discord API at: [https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord-api-events]

Sorry about the link, I don't know how to hiperlink it.